# Error starting nodejs: openssl config failed

Tags: node.js, express

Got the following error starting Express node:

> openssl config failed: error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such
>   process

The node start anyway.
I am not attempting to use SSL.

Here the starting code:

```
...
app = Express;
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || config.port);
try {

    var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
        console.log('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().address + ':' + server.address().port);
    });
} catch (e) {
    log.fatal(e);
}
```

Only happens on deploy server. Running in developer machine starts ok.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem was that Express looks for the environment variable `OPENSSL_CONF` to lookup to SSL configuration file.

The variable `OPENSSL_CONF` was pointing to a non existence location on the drive.
I removed from the system and the message disappear.

Note: must use a new console to launch the node so environment variable `OPENSSL_CONF` is not present. Or simple deleted on the current console.

Additional information at [github](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17261)

Answer (score 9):

Removing global environment variable OPENSSL_CONF (leftover from previous troubleshooting) solved my problem.

Running on Windows you might try:

Set environment in local command window and verify problem:

```
set OPENSSL_CONF=c:\dummy  
npm -v
```

=> you now probably see this ssl error message

Remove environment and verify problem is gone:

```
set OPENSSL_CONF=
npm -v
```

=> no ssl error message

Source: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17261

Comment: wonderful answer

Answer (score 4):

Please check the System Variables and confirm if the location of openssl.cnf file listed there is correct. Cross check it and update the location in System Variables.
[image: Sys variable image]