# openssl config failed: error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process in Appcelerator studio

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm getting this error in ***appcelerator studio***:

> openssl config failed: error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process

I could not find anyone with the same problem so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error starting nodejs: openssl config failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52188224/error-starting-nodejs-openssl-config-failed)

Answer (score 12):

Tried a few suggestions from the [npm repository issues](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17261):

1. Remove environment variable `OPENSSL_CONF` using command

```
set OPENSSL_CONF=
```

This works but after restarting the computer the error is back again.

2. Removed `OPENSSL_CONF` from Environment Variables

Go to the Windows Environment Variables and remove `OPENSSL_CONF` from the System variables. Save it and restart the editor and it works like a charm.

[image]

Comment: Yes removing the OPENSSL_CONF environment variable and relaunching the cmd made the trick for me.

Comment: Removed OPENSSL_CONF from Environment Variables did the trick for me. Installing PostgreSQL somehow set this env for me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a NPM error with OpenSSL according to this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52188374/5193915
or the included GitHub link (https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17261)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue , you should install open ssl :

[openssl](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue with these steps, should try once:

1. In C disk, create OpenSSL/bin/openssl.cnf
2. In [example config file](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man5/config.html) here, you can copy and paste to openssl.cnf file
3. Now open command prompt in administrator mode. Now set system variable of openssl to OpenSSL/bin/openssl.cnf by this script: `setx /m OPENSSL_CONF "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl.cnf"`
4. It should show **SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.** in windows.
5. Now open "system environment variables" program -> Environment Variables
6. It should show [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gwiie.png). Or you can edit the **OPENSSL_CONF** value to **C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl.cnf** by manual
7. After all above steps, close all programs and try again with npm commands. It should have fixed. ;)

Answer (score 0):

For Linux, run `echo "$OPENSSL_CONF"` to see what you have that environment variable set to. If it is set to something, try `unset OPENSSL_CONF` to unset it. You may have it set to something in your `~/.bashrc` file, `~/.profile` file, or `~/.bash_aliases` file which is causing it to get set again each time you reboot or open a new shell.